# Hadoop datanode fail during scala program execution

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am having the following error when trying to execute a spark program written in scala. Does anyone know what it means?

```
2015-08-17 15:38:26,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629 (Datanode Uuid null) service to hadoop-master/192.168.1.62:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2015-08-17 15:38:26,230 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool Block pool BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629 (Datanode Uuid null) service to hadoop-master/192.168.1.62:8020 successfully registered with NN
2015-08-17 15:38:26,230 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: For namenode hadoop-master/192.168.1.62:8020 using DELETEREPORT_INTERVAL of 300000 msec  BLOCKREPORT_INTERVAL of 21600000msec CACHEREPORT_INTERVAL of 10000msec Initial delay: 0msec; heartBeatInterval=3000
2015-08-17 15:38:26,271 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Namenode Block pool BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629 (Datanode Uuid 8534c56b-65ff-476b-8e03-f6fd70fbeab4) service to hadoop-master/192.168.1.62:8020 trying to claim ACTIVE state with txid=35908
2015-08-17 15:38:26,271 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Acknowledging ACTIVE Namenode Block pool BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629 (Datanode Uuid 8534c56b-65ff-476b-8e03-f6fd70fbeab4) service to hadoop-master/192.168.1.62:8020
2015-08-17 15:38:26,299 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Successfully sent block report 0xb2d92a4e40e,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 1. The reports had 51 total blocks and used 1 RPC(s). This took 3 msec to generate and 25 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back one command: FinalizeCommand/5.
2015-08-17 15:38:26,299 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Got finalize command for block pool BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629
2015-08-17 15:38:58,683 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744605_3805 src: /192.168.1.64:41006 dest: /192.168.1.64:50010
2015-08-17 15:39:03,785 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/var/data/hadoop/hdfs/dn, DS-c0f8f924-63a2-4e79-a4b2-c34f66e00e60): Scheduling suspect block BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073742412_1589 for rescanning.
2015-08-17 15:39:03,787 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/var/data/hadoop/hdfs/dn, DS-c0f8f924-63a2-4e79-a4b2-c34f66e00e60) exiting because of exception 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner.runLoop(VolumeScanner.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner.run(VolumeScanner.java:619)
2015-08-17 15:39:03,788 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/var/data/hadoop/hdfs/dn, DS-c0f8f924-63a2-4e79-a4b2-c34f66e00e60) exiting.
2015-08-17 15:40:58,578 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.64:41006, dest: /192.168.1.64:50010, bytes: 134217728, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_130977062_1, offset: 0, srvID: 8534c56b-65ff-476b-8e03-f6fd70fbeab4, blockid: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744605_3805, duration: 119724733298
2015-08-17 15:40:58,582 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744605_3805, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-08-17 15:40:58,608 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744606_3806 src: /192.168.1.64:41021 dest: /192.168.1.64:50010
2015-08-17 15:41:16,324 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.64:41021, dest: /192.168.1.64:50010, bytes: 134217728, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_130977062_1, offset: 0, srvID: 8534c56b-65ff-476b-8e03-f6fd70fbeab4, blockid: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744606_3806, duration: 17693650243
2015-08-17 15:41:16,324 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744606_3806, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-08-17 15:41:16,355 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744607_3807 src: /192.168.1.64:41024 dest: /192.168.1.64:50010
2015-08-17 15:41:33,434 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.64:41024, dest: /192.168.1.64:50010, bytes: 134217728, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_130977062_1, offset: 0, srvID: 8534c56b-65ff-476b-8e03-f6fd70fbeab4, blockid: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744607_3807, duration: 17072947884
2015-08-17 15:41:33,434 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744607_3807, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-08-17 15:41:33,455 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744608_3808 src: /192.168.1.64:41026 dest: /192.168.1.64:50010
2015-08-17 15:41:50,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.64:41026, dest: /192.168.1.64:50010, bytes: 134217728, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_130977062_1, offset: 0, srvID: 8534c56b-65ff-476b-8e03-f6fd70fbeab4, blockid: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744608_3808, duration: 17141980857
2015-08-17 15:41:50,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744608_3808, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-08-17 15:41:50,686 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744609_3809 src: /192.168.1.64:41029 dest: /192.168.1.64:50010
2015-08-17 15:42:07,050 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.64:41029, dest: /192.168.1.64:50010, bytes: 134217728, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_130977062_1, offset: 0, srvID: 8534c56b-65ff-476b-8e03-f6fd70fbeab4, blockid: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744609_3809, duration: 16356245249
2015-08-17 15:42:07,050 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744609_3809, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-08-17 15:42:07,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744610_3810 src: /192.168.1.64:41031 dest: /192.168.1.64:50010
2015-08-17 15:42:24,283 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception for BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744610_3810
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opWriteBlock(Receiver.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-17 15:42:24,879 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744610_3810, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE: Thread is interrupted.
2015-08-17 15:42:24,879 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744610_3810, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-08-17 15:42:24,879 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: opWriteBlock BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744610_3810 received exception java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
2015-08-17 15:42:25,109 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: ubuntu-hadoop-3:50010:DataXceiver error processing WRITE_BLOCK operation  src: /192.168.1.64:41031 dst: /192.168.1.64:50010
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream$Reader.performIO(SocketInputStream.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opWriteBlock(Receiver.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-08-17 15:44:30,211 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/var/data/hadoop/hdfs/dn, DS-c0f8f924-63a2-4e79-a4b2-c34f66e00e60): Scheduling suspect block BP-133353882-127.0.1.1-1438188921629:blk_1073744609_3809 for rescanning.
```

It seems that when I had this some days before I managed to overcome it by emptying the cleaning up the datanode. However, I am not even sure this is what fixed it and surely this cannot be a proper solution.

Many thanks

Comment: looks like purely Hadoop problem

Comment: The thing is, it always happens on the same datanode

Comment: The log message says that the HDFS client closed the network connection in the middle of writing a block.  The client would be a Spark worker that was running on the same machine (based on the IP address).  I'd suggest looking at the log output from the Spark worker to see why it closed the connection.

Comment: Indeed it seems you are right. You should post it as answer, not comment, so that others see it.